# jQuery .click and media queries

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I have this small jQuery snippet:

```
jQuery('.openSubMenu').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

This is to open/close a nav submenu.  I have 2 media queries, `@media only screen and (max-width : 568px)` and `@media only screen and (min-width : 569px) and (max-width : 974px)`.

The above jQuery only works in the less than 568 media query, it does nothing once the screen is past 568 pixels.  I've tried writing a full direct path to the submenu I wish to open, and yet it still does nothing.  There are no errors in the console also.

The HTML is a pretty basic unordered list, below is an example:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="openSubMenu"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The second level `<ul></ul>` is initially set to `display:none`.  Like I said though, the click function works fine sub 568 pixels in screen width, but not above.  The CSS in both media queries for this list is nearly the same aside from some positioning changes.

Comment: Stupid question but, you are using a CSS3 supported browser?

Comment: Yes, I am.  This happens in all browsers as well.

Comment: Cool, just thought I'd ask.  have you tried removing the max-width requirement from the 2nd media query and testing if that works?

Comment: Yes as well.  I have literally tried everything I can think of for past hour.  I have gotten no where with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that after resizing the screen the .click function from above was somehow being lost (for lack of a better term).  I added in something to watch for the resize and then add the jQuery snippet again after resize and it seemed to fix my issue.  I'd still like to know why this occurred and it there is a better solution.

Here's the amended jQuery that seems to have fixed it:

```
jQuery('.openSubMenu').click(function() {   
    jQuery(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle();
});

jQuery(window).smartresize(function() {
    jQuery('.openSubMenu').click(function() {   
        jQuery(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```